# search hash values into another hash and create a new hash with matching values

Tags: ruby, loops, ruby-hash

In a Ruby project where I have the two hashes below (from two models): "users" and "conflicts".

I would like to find the way to iterate them in order to search conflicts'values within users'values and get a hash that would contain, for each conflict, which users would contain all its values:

```
users = {
  'user1' => ['resp1', 'resp2', 'resp3', 'resp4'],
  'user2' => ['resp1', 'resp2', 'resp3', 'resp4'],
  'user3' => ['resp1', 'resp4']
}

conflicts = {
  'c1'=> ['resp1', 'resp2'], 'c2'=> ['resp1', 'resp3'],
  'c3'=> ['resp1', 'resp4'], 'c4'=> ['resp3', 'resp5','resp6']
}
```

Desired result:

```
conflict_users = {
  'c1'=> ['user1', 'user2'], 'c2'=> ['user1', 'user2'],
  'c3'=> ['user1', 'user2','user3'],'c4'=> ['nill']
}
```

-- Any idea on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: is this your input: `{'resp1', 'resp2', 'resp3', 'resp4'}`? or is more like a list: `['resp1', 'resp2', 'resp3', 'resp4']`?

Comment: Thanks everyone!, I have amended the question to make it clearer following your comments/questions.

Answer (score 4):

The desired return value can be obtained as follows.

```
conflicts.transform_values do |c_resps|
  users.each_with_object([]) do |(user,user_resps),c_users|
    c_users << user if (c_resps & user_resps) == c_resps
  end.tap { |c_users| c_users.replace(['nill']) if c_users.empty? }
end
  #=> {"c1"=>["user1", "user2"], "c2"=>["user1", "user2"],
  #    "c3"=>["user1", "user2", "user3"], "c4"=>["nill"]}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-26) and [#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap).

`(c_resps & user_resps)` in

```
c_users << user if (c_resps & user_resps) == c_resps
```

is an array containing all elements in `c_resps` (a value in `conflicts`) that are also in `user_resps` (a value in `users`). Therefore all elements in `c_resps` are contained in `user_resps` if and only if `(c_resps & user_resps) == c_resps`<sup>1</sup>.

Note that it would be easier (and more Ruby-like) to leave `"c4"=>["nill"]` as `"c4"=>[]`, in which case `.tap { |c_users| c_users.replace(['nill']) if arr1.empty? }` could be removed.

To help you understand what is going on I've reorganized the method slightly and inserted `puts` statements to display the values of different objects when the method is run.

```
conflicts.transform_values do |c_resps|
  puts "\nc_resps = #{c_resps}"
  c_users = []
  users.each do |user,user_resps|
    puts "  user=#{user}, user_resps=#{user_resps}"
    puts "  c_resps & user_resps = #{c_resps & user_resps}"
    c_users << user if (c_resps & user_resps) == c_resps
    puts "  c_users after c_users << user if... = #{c_users}"
  end
  c_users = ['nill'] if c_users.empty?
  puts "c_users after c_users = ['nill'] if c_users.empty? = #{c_users}"
  c_users
end      #=> {"c1"=>["user1", "user2"], "c2"=>["user1", "user2"],
  #    "c3"=>["user1", "user2", "user3"], "c4"=>["nill"]}
```

This displays the following.

```
c_resps = ["resp1", "resp2"]
  user=user1, user_resps=["resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1", "resp2"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1"]
  user=user2, user_resps=["resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1", "resp2"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1", "user2"]
  user=user3, user_resps=["resp1", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1", "user2"]
c_users after c_users = ['nill'] if c_users.empty? = ["user1", "user2"]
```

```
c_resps = ["resp1", "resp3"]
  user=user1, user_resps=["resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1", "resp3"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1"]
  user=user2, user_resps=["resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1", "resp3"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1", "user2"]
  user=user3, user_resps=["resp1", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1", "user2"]
c_users after c_users = ['nill'] if c_users.empty? = ["user1", "user2"]
```

```
c_resps = ["resp1", "resp4"]
  user=user1, user_resps=["resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1", "resp4"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1"]
  user=user2, user_resps=["resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1", "resp4"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1", "user2"]
  user=user3, user_resps=["resp1", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp1", "resp4"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
c_users after c_users = ['nill'] if c_users.empty? = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
```

```
c_resps = ["resp3", "resp5", "resp6"]
  user=user1, user_resps=["resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp3"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = []
  user=user2, user_resps=["resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = ["resp3"]
  c_users after c_users << user if... = []
  user=user3, user_resps=["resp1", "resp4"]
  c_resps & user_resps = []
  c_users after c_users << user if... = []
c_users after c_users = ['nill'] if c_users.empty? = ["nill"]
```

<sup>1. `(c_resps & v) == c_resps` could be replaced with (among others) `(v-c_resps).empty?` or `arr1 << k if v.all? { |e| c_resps.include?(e) }`.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I would first transform the `users` structure, so you can lookup all users by providing a `resp`.

```
require 'set'

users = {
  'user1' => ['resp1', 'resp2', 'resp3', 'resp4'],
  'user2' => ['resp1', 'resp2', 'resp3', 'resp4'],
  'user3' => ['resp1', 'resp4'],
}

users_by_resp = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Set[] } 

users.each do |user, resps|
  resps.each { |resp| users_by_resp[resp] << user }
end

# optional, disable the creation of new sets when accessing unknown keys
users_by_resp.default = Set[]

# resulting in the following structure
pp users_by_resp
# {"resp1"=>#<Set: {"user1", "user2", "user3"}>,
#  "resp2"=>#<Set: {"user1", "user2"}>,
#  "resp3"=>#<Set: {"user1", "user2"}>,
#  "resp4"=>#<Set: {"user1", "user2", "user3"}>}
```

Then transform the values of the `conflicts` hash. First you get the users of each `resp`, then only keep those that are present in all resps. (By taking the intersection of all the sets.)

```
conflicts = {
  'c1'=> ['resp1', 'resp2'],
  'c2'=> ['resp1', 'resp3'],
  'c3'=> ['resp1', 'resp4'],
  'c4'=> ['resp3', 'resp5','resp6'],
}

result = conflicts.transform_values do |resps|
  resps.map(&users_by_resp).reduce(:&).to_a
end

pp result 
# {"c1"=>["user1", "user2"],
#  "c2"=>["user1", "user2"],
#  "c3"=>["user1", "user2", "user3"],
#  "c4"=>[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that input, a simple way to do it is as follow:

```rb
users = {
  'user1' => ['resp1', 'resp2', 'resp3', 'resp4'],
  'user2' => ['resp1', 'resp2', 'resp3', 'resp4'],
  'user3' => ['resp1', 'resp4']
}

conflicts = {
  'c1'=> ['resp1', 'resp2'], 'c2'=> ['resp1', 'resp3'],
  'c3'=> ['resp1', 'resp4'], 'c4'=> ['resp3', 'resp5','resp6']
}

result = users.inject({}) do |conflicts_result , (k_user, v_user)|
    conflicts.each_with_object(conflicts_result) do |(k_conflict, v_conflict), conflicts_result |
        conflicts_result[k_conflict] ||= []
        conflicts_result[k_conflict] << k_user if (v_conflict - v_user).size.zero?
    end
end.each {|k, v| v << 'nill' if v.size.zero?}



p result
```

You can test the snipper above [here](https://repl.it/languages/ruby?v2=1), also here are some docs: [Inject](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject),  [Ruby each for hash](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/each)